# Configure HTTP Post headers and body to send Twilio request

Tags: http, post, twilio, urlencode

I am trying to get my custom built HTTP Post request to execute the following call to twilio

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/xxxxx/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=+15558675309'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+15017250604'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?'  \
-d 'MediaUrl=https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg' \
-u xxxxx:your_auth_token
```

My custom built request accepts **an URL, headers and a body**, similar to the HTTP Post form at Hurl.it.

How do I translate the portions

```
--data-urlencode
```

and

```
-d
```

into my URL, headers and body?

Example: The -u part I put into a header with "Authorization: Basic ", and it worked perfectly, the server recognises me. I just can't get it to recognise the From, To, Body parts.

Tks!

Comment: They are your POST variables. How are you making the HTTP POST?

Comment: Which variables? Http requests with the verb POST have a precise specification. The libraries that implement the protocol should mean little. For the purpose of this you can assume The http post is being sent in serial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Both the `-d` and `--data-urlencode` flags indicate adding data to the POST request body. The data also needs to be url encoded. When the request is made, all the url encoded data is concatenated with ampersands and sent as the body.

In the case of your example, the POST request body would end up looking like this:

```
To=%2B15558675309&From=%2B15017250604&Body=This%20is%20the%20ship%20that%20made%20the%20Kessel%20Run%20in%20fourteen%20parsecs%3F&MediaUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fc1.staticflickr.com%2F3%2F2899%2F14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get it to work. My application only allows content type to be "application/json". 

Does twilio accept only "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"? @philnash

Comment: Yup, you need to provide the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. What do you mean your application only allows json? Can't you program around it?

Comment: our app was made to support only the most common type of content-type used to interact with modern web services. That is application/json. 

we can obviously change it but it will expose further problems. we definitely can be more flexible, but so far we've yet to encounter any major platforms requiring such implementation. We are integrating with fb, google, google maps (etc) and quite many other APIs, and none has such requirement. 

we can use your libraries to integrate, but for some of the particular use cases of our users, lets just say its sub-optimal to only have that option.

Comment: Here's a suggestion then, build yourself a Node.js [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/functions) that takes in a webhook from Twilio, translates the content from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json` and sends it on to your application?

Comment: Hmmm... or indeed the other way around. You're trying to send requests to Twilio, you could do the translation the other way around, making the call to a Twilio Function that relays it on to Twilio in the correct format.

Comment: Let me know how you get on with it!